# What OS name does Windows 10 set to browser's user agent?

Tags: javascript, browser, user-agent, windows-10

It is possible to check in browser's `navigator.userAgent` the operation system of the user. I know we can't rely on browser's user agent because it can be spoofed, but we need it for a statistics purpose only. For `Windows` environments, value `Windows NT 6.3` stands for Win 8.1, `Windows NT 6.2` for Win 8, `Windows NT 6.1` for Win 7 and so on. Could anyone advise what value does Windows 10 put in user agent?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

@NulledPointer has pointed out that [the IE user agent will contain *Windows NT 10.0*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx). This is true as of the November 2014 CTP of Windows 10. That particular CTP introduces [IE Edge Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/11/11/living-on-the-edge-our-next-step-in-interoperability.aspx), which will be the only operating mode available for the release version of Windows 10. Here is a sample user agent string from @NulledPointer's link:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0

Comment: Thank you for the clue, I assume it won't change for a release version.

Comment: Its `Windows NT 10.0` now! check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks @NulledPointer, I added some info from your link.